# iptables --dport ssh

Tags: ssh, firewall, iptables

In iptables, what is the difference between --dport ssh and --dport 22? i.e. when I change the port in sshd's settings, will iptables automatically get the new port and use that wherever --dport ssh is specified, or will it still use 22?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a name it will do a look-up on what is defined in your `/etc/services`.  What you have defined in your openssh's `sshd_config` is completely irrelevant.  The name is only evaluated when the rule is being added to the kernel tables.  Once the rule has been added, any subsequent changes to `/etc/services` do not automatically result in a change of the rule.